# How can I "Highlight" a search word at webBrowser control?

Tags: c#, search, highlight

[EDIT]

I have tried two workarounds already (before make this post).
Both of them were not working.
The flow of execution never went into it(Yes, it should be..).

-I guess, there should be some error, invisible error(s). That keeps the flow of exectuion from going into it. The program shows some screen though it looks like a normal one but it's not. It is a kind of half place.

```
 if (e.Url.AbsolutePath == (sender as WebBrowser).Url.AbsolutePath)
```

or

```
 if (webBrowser1.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
```

[End EDIT]

I have searched the word "stomach" at Google and hilighted it wih Yellow_color.

I had a good result.

```
public static string myTerm = "stomach";   
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.google.co.kr/search?&q=" + myTerm);                       
    webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
    WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
}
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{   
    IHTMLDocument2 myDoc = webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument as IHTMLDocument2;
    StringBuilder myContents = new StringBuilder(myDoc.body.outerHTML);
    string myColoring = "<span style='background-color:yellow'>" + myTerm + "</span>";
    myContents.Replace(myTerm, myColoring);
    Regex myRex = new Regex(myColoring);
    myDoc.body.innerHTML = myRex.Replace(myContents.ToString(), myTerm, 6);  
    // I do not want to see codes at search_textbox itself, so I figured out '6' is a good number.
}
```

Now, I used the same code to my Local_Website.

This time, I have infinite looping.

I guess the serach text box going again and again.

```
public static string myTerm = "stomach";   
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.kmle.co.kr/search.php?Search=" + myTerm);                      
    webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
    WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
}
int myCount = 0;
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (myCount == 10)   //  I do not want endless loop.
        return;
    myCount++;
    IHTMLDocument2 myDoc = webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument as IHTMLDocument2;
    StringBuilder myContents = new StringBuilder(myDoc.body.outerHTML);
    string myColoring =  "<span style='background-color:yellow'>" + myTerm + "</span>";
    myContents.Replace(myTerm, myColoring);
    myDoc.body.innerHTML = myContents.ToString();
}
```

Is there any good hints ? How can I have my goal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with the DocumentCompleted() firing multiple times.
it works on Google because their website is "simpler"(doesn't have ajax or hidden frames) in contrast to the the one you're trying to load .

try limiting your code to only invoke when the document is actually done loading

```
if ( (e.Url.AbsolutePath == (sender as WebBrowser).Url.AbsolutePath) ) 
{
    //do your magic here.
};
```

so your document complete function should look like this:

```
    private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Url.AbsolutePath == (sender as WebBrowser).Url.AbsolutePath)
        { 
            IHTMLDocument2 myDoc = webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument as IHTMLDocument2;
            StringBuilder myContents = new StringBuilder(myDoc.body.outerHTML);
            string myColoring = "<span style='background-color:yellow'>" + myTerm + "</span>";
            myContents.Replace(myTerm, myColoring);
            myDoc.body.innerHTML = myContents.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Nah....... I've tried two line of them. //if (e.Url.AbsolutePath == (sender as WebBrowser).Url.AbsolutePath)
//if (webBrowser1.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) Of couse, they did not work. They did not catch. I mean useless. Absoulutely.